Gymnasium env.render() runs but nothing pop up
I am trying to visualize the gymnasium environment by using the render method.
Here is my code
import time
import gymnasium as gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1', render_mode="rgb_array")
env.reset()
env.render()
time.sleep(1)

The code successfully runs but nothing shows up.

If you want a render window to "show up" you have to use render_mode=human
See https://gymnasium.farama.org/main/api/env/#gymnasium.Env.render for more details
